# Guitar Pedal not functioning at all, no sound created

Tags: pcb, sound

Ok, so I'll do my best to explain my situation. (FYI, I am a beginner)

I'm building an overdrive pedal for a school project which I plan on modding with the help from a teacher. However, I thought I did all the steps correctly but when I plug it in, it just kills all the sound (no sound comes from the amp). Is it possibly a problem with my wiring or my circuit?

I'm attempting to follow the instructions for the pedal from this website:
http://www.instructables.com/id/Overdrive-Pedal/?ALLSTEPS

And here are some pictures of my project:
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
All help is appreciated and if someone thinks that they can help me and needs more pictures and details, please contact me. Thanks to you all!

Comment: It's impossible to help here unless you give at least two more pieces of information: 1) The schematics for what this is supposed to do, and 2) A clear picture on the back of your board, so we can see how everything is connected.

Comment: I don't see a connected ground. Maybe it came loose and messed things up? In the last pic I mean

Comment: @pipe I will attach a picture of the back and the schematic can be found on the link I attached

Comment: @AlexanderM I disconnected the circuit from the board, if thats what you mean

Comment: You say "100 log" and "100 linear" in reference to the potentiometers, do you mean "100k"? 100k (100,000 Ohms) is very, very different than 100 Ohms.

Comment: @rdtsc Yes, I do mean 100K. Sorry, I should have been more specific. It says that on the link I attached.

Comment: Please note that links to external websites may go away at any time, making your question obsolete. That is why it is important to attach the necessary information to your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From your updated picture of the back of your PCB it seems as if no component is connected to any other component. This will obviously not make a circuit. Your problem is that you are not using the same type of PCB as they do in the guide you are following.

You are using what is often called a *perfboard* where all the pads are isolated. They are using a very special type of *stripboard* (which I can not link to because the RadioShack website is seriously broken), but here is a picture of a similar type:
[image: TriPad PCB]
Note the difference between this and the type you have chosen.

If you want to read more about the different types, you can find information on Wikipedia about [stripboards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stripboard)

Your board is not completely ruined. Assuming you have wired everything correctly, you can add the missing connections by soldering short pieces of metal in exactly the same place as the RadioShack board would connect them. Hopefully you saved all the pins that you cut off from the resistors - they will come in handy now!

Comment: I tried googling "65200J2H", the only identifier on the green perfboard, and found nothing. Highly doubt any manufacturer of perfboard used internal connections, but wanted to check. Stumbled upon a [nice link](http://www.seymourduncan.com/tonefiend/wp-content/uploads/4-v021.pdf) to transferring schematic to perfboard, goes into some detail about adding components and how to wire them properly.

Comment: If I have a veroboard will it do the same thing as a strip board? Like this one: http://www.amazon.com/Prototype-Universal-Stripboard-76x101mm-1200hole/dp/B0073X57MI/ref=sr_1_4?ie=UTF8&qid=1448904699&sr=8-4&keywords=stripboard

Comment: Not really, the problem with the instructable you linked to is that they use a very custom type of veroboard with patterns that I have not seen before. If you look closely at the picture of the board from the instructables it has a lighter shade where the copper connects: http://www.instructables.com/files/orig/F0W/5RG2/HJ5ZYAVP/F0W5RG2HJ5ZYAVP.jpg  Worst case, you can only get this board on RadioShack.

Comment: @pipe one last question (sorry) can I just make solder bridges between where they should meet up on the board from the intstructable?

Comment: Yep, that should work fine